# D3 - Apply gradient to a group

Tags: d3.js

I would like to apply a gradient to the y-axis. So far, when I apply the gradient, the gradient appears on each individual number instead of smoothly flowing through the whole thing.

The gradient:

```
var grad_y_axis = svg.append('defs')
  .append('linearGradient')
  .attr({
    'id' : 'grad_y_axis',
    'x1' : '0%',
    'x2' : '0%',
    'y1' : '0%',
    'y2' : '100%'
  });

grad_y_axis.append('stop')
  .attr('offset', '0%')
  .style('stop-color', 'red')
  .style('stop-opacity', '0.0');

grad_y_axis.append('stop')
  .attr('offset', '40%')
  .style('stop-color', 'green')
  .style('stop-opacity', '1');

grad_y_axis.append('stop')
  .attr('offset', '60%')
  .style('stop-color', 'green')
  .style('stop-opacity', '1');

grad_y_axis.append('stop')
  .attr('offset', '100%')
  .style('stop-color', 'red')
  .style('stop-opacity', '0.0');
```

The application:

```
svg.select('.y_axis')
  .attr('fill', 'url(#grad_y_axis)');
```

Essentially, what is happening is the gradient is getting applied to each individual item, even though I assigned to the whole group!

Comment: Have you tried this attribute? gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"

Comment: Not yet. I'll give it a try now.